# how to persist tabs in android app

Tags: android

i have five tabs in first screen of my app, i want tabs to remain consistent in whole app, means when i move to new activity, these also visible in that screen. please give me some suggestions, thanks in advance. here is code of tabs

```
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Home.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home")
            .setIndicator("Home", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.select))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Hypnosis.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("hypnosis")
            .setIndicator("Hypnosis", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.select))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SelfDevelopment.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("self development")
            .setIndicator("Self Development",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.select)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Read.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("read")
            .setIndicator("Read", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.select))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Faq.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("faq")
            .setIndicator("FAQ", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.select))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1):

I exactly understand your problem, for making TabBar consistent throughout your application, you have to implement nested activities inside the Tab Activity.

For the best example of Nested Activities inside Tab Activity, go through this example: http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/ , i have also implemented this in my one of the app, its working fine.